# Laravel Eloquent toArray / toJson with Carbon Date

Tags: php, laravel, serialization, laravel-4, php-carbon

I have a model with a date declared as Carbon

```
public $dates = array('created_at', 'submitted_at');
```

When I try to convert the model to array with `->toArray()` or when creating a json response, I get an error :

```
[2015-02-10 12:25:02] local.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Data missing' in /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php:385
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(2671): Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.000', '2015-02-09 16:0...')
#1 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(2276): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->asDateTime('2015-02-09 16:0...')
#2 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(2255): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->attributesToArray()
#3 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(707): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->toArray()
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\Support\Collection->Illuminate\Support\{closure}(Object(app\Entities\Order))
#5 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(709): array_map(Object(Closure), Array)
#6 /var/www/public/app.orders/app/controllers/OrdersController.php(49): Illuminate\Support\Collection->toArray()
#7 [internal function]: OrdersController->index('37')
#8 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(231): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(93): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('index', Array)
#10 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(62): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(OrdersController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'index')
#11 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(962): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'OrdersControlle...', 'index')
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}('37')
#13 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(109): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#14 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1028): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(996): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(775): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(745): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#19 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#20 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#21 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#22 /var/www/public/app.orders/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(641): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /var/www/public/app.orders/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#24 {main} [] []
```

If I remove the DateMutator, everything goes well, but I'd like to keep it as MSSQL dates retrieved aren't really user fiendly.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and I only found a workaround. It seems that the toArray function calls the following:

`Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.000',`...

in your version and in mine:

`Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',`...

and somehow not all requested data (year/month...minutes/seconds) are provided in the object.

So what I did was that in the Model events, that bring or store the model to the DB, I fix the dates manualy, assuming that the rest of the code does not provide "invalid" values to those dates. Of course if at some point provide invalid values to those dates and call the `toArray` method before any save to the DB, the problem still occures.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function($record){
        if (empty($record->the_date_attribute)) {
            // Perhaps set a default value here
        } else {
            if($record->the_date_attribute instanceof \Carbon\Carbon)
                $record->the_date_attribute->setTime(0,0,0);
        }
     }
    static::restored(function($record){
        if (empty($record->the_date_attribute)) {
            // Perhaps set a default value here
        } else {
            if($record->the_date_attribute instanceof \Carbon\Carbon)
                $record->the_date_attribute->setTime(0,0,0);
        }
     }
}
```

In my case I set the time to 0, since in my DB the field is of date type.
Another possible workaround is to override the toArray method and provide there the extra data, but I prefer the events aprroach as the data to the DB are stored with the values as I need them to.

In your case the solution might be simpler. Perhaps you provide time information but you do not provide the seconds...?

Answer (score 0):

My2c

I resolved by adding microseconds to format definition in each model that uses SqlServer

`protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';`

I'd like to know if there's a way to configure it as default for every model